# Increase the length of line in legend in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, jfreereport

I am rendering a line chart using JFreechart. I need help to modify legend which is being rendered by the JFree. I need to increase the length of line in legend area. Below image shows the current output.

[image]

Below images shows what I want to achieve

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using the code below:

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
renderer.setLegendLine(new Line2D.Double(-20.0D, 0.0D, 20.0D, 0.0D));
```